# How to pass logged user from control to vuejs component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

in  laravel 8/2.6/bootstrap 4.6/Axios app I want to pass logged user from control to vuejs component:

```
public function index()
{
    $loggedUser = auth()->user();
    return view('chat', [
        'loggedUser' => $loggedUser,
    ]);
}
```

in blade file :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="container chats">
        loggedUser::{{ $loggedUser}}!!!!!!!!!
<!-- I SEE USER data above : -->

        <user-rooms :loggedUser="{{ $loggedUser }}"> </user-rooms>
    </div>

@endsection
```

and vue component :

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        loggedUser::{{ loggedUser}}
        <!-- I see empty value above outputed -->
    </div>

</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "Chat",
    components: {},

    props: {
        loggedUser : {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },

    mounted() {
        console.log('UserRooms.vue Component mounted loggedUser')
        console.log(this.loggedUser)    // I see undefined outputed
    }, // mounted() {


};
</script>
```

I tried several direrent cases like :

```
<user-rooms :loggedUser="{{ json_encode($loggedUser) }}"> </user-rooms>
```

but failed anyway...

Which way is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: save logged in user in store at the moment user log in to the systsem. then get the user from it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow these steps to pass `auth` user in `vue component`.

You should add a `<meta name="user" content="{{ Auth::user() }}">` in

> // app.blade.php or whatever you have maybe master.blade.php like below

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    @if (Auth::check()) 
      <meta name="user" content="{{ Auth::user() }}">
    @endif 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" 
  ...
  ...
```

and then in your component inside data object do this action:

```
 data() {
        return {
            
            loggedUser : document.querySelector("meta[name='user']").getAttribute('content')
        }
    },
```

and you should see the `logged` in `user` in `component` `mounted` method:

```
 mounted() {
        console.log(this.loggedUser);
    },
```

and now you can use the user `object` in every where of your `component`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get logged in information with this example:

lets say app.blade.php its your file that loads your page.
You can set a script that stores your authentication.

```
<script>
  window.user = {{!! Auth::user() !!}} 
</script>
```

Then in your vue component or even better if you are using vuex store you can get the object.

```
data(){
  loggedUser: window.user
}
```